# Get full log output from a Python logging instance

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to get a string containing all the formatted log output that's written to the console with the Python logging module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Is this possible? Do I need to subclass logging, overwrite logging._log method and save every record output in my own log output variable or is there something like this already?

I would prefer a solution like this, and not reading from a log output file for example.

Comment: If the `logging` module is the only piece of code that is producing output then you could simply replace `sys.stdout` with something that both outputs to the console and saves the contents somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Bakuriu, it would actually work in my case, but I would like to go for a more long-term solution..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what are you looking for.

If you want to create a logger that logs on two different files you have to add two handlers to your logger, like explained here: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#multiple-handlers-and-formatters

Comment: No, I need access to the total string at runtime.

Comment: well, if you read carefully the link i've provided, there's the possibility to add to the logger a StreamHandler and store the log stream in a file-like object (i.e. StringIO) http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler